# How to segue or show/push new view in Xcode and swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a table view cell and that cell is in a table view and that table view is in a ViewController and that view controller is in a page view controller and finally that page view controller is a tab in a tabbed view controller.  For every cell in the table view I have a button and I want to show a be ViewController when that button is pressed (programmatically) I want the new view controller to not be inside the tabbed bar controller. How do I do this

This is the layers of the storyboard 
Button -> table view cell -> table view -> ViewController -> Page view controller -> tabbed bar controller

This is my tableviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class TimelineViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
var cellTypes = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupBackground(backgroundImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Placeholder 1.jpeg"))
    setViewToProfileViewController()
}

func setupBackground(backgroundImage: UIImage) {
    backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage

    // Background Image Blur Effect:
    let backgroundImageBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let backgroundImageBlurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: backgroundImageBlurEffect)
    backgroundImageBlurEffectView.frame = backgroundImageView.frame
    backgroundImageView.addSubview(backgroundImageBlurEffectView)
}

// Change View Controller To Profle View Controller
func setViewToProfileViewController() {
    print("H")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 15
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell", for: indexPath) as! TimelineCell

    // Decide Which Cell To Create
    switch cellTypes[indexPath.row] {
    case 1:
        cell = cell.createPartyCell(cellToUse: cell)
        tableView.rowHeight = 220
    case 2:
        cell = cell.createPostCell(cellToUse: cell)
        tableView.rowHeight = 195
    case 3:
        cell = cell.createFriendRequestCell(cellToUse: cell)
        tableView.rowHeight = 120
    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}

}
```

This is my tableviewcellClass

```
import UIKit

class TimelineCell: UITableViewCell {

let timelineViewController = TimelineViewController()

//Initialize Storyboard Elements
@IBOutlet weak var timelineCellView: UIView!

// Initialize Properties
let cellTitle = UILabel()
let cellBackgroundImageView = UIImageView()
let cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .prominent))
let profileObject = ProfileObject(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Placeholder 1.jpeg"), width: 32, height: 32)
let cellDateLabel = UILabel()
let cellDescriptionBackground = UILabel()
let cellDescription = UITextView()
let cellImageView = UIImageView()
let cellNameLabel = UILabel()


// Prepare For Cell Reuse
override func prepareForReuse() {
    // Recycle Cell Subviews
    cellTitle.removeFromSuperview()
    cellBackgroundImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    cellDateLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    cellDescriptionBackground.removeFromSuperview()
    cellDescription.removeFromSuperview()
    cellImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    cellNameLabel.removeFromSuperview()
}

@objc func profileObjectClick(){
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PERFORME THE SEGUE
}


 // - - - - - CREATE - - - - -
// - - - - - CELLS - - - - -

// CREATE PARTY CELL
func createPartyCell(cellToUse postCell: TimelineCell) -> TimelineCell {

    // Initialize Party Cell View
    timelineCellView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    timelineCellView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Initialize Party Cell Background Image
    cellBackgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: timelineCellView.frame.width, height: 200)
    cellBackgroundImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Placeholder 1.jpeg")
    cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView.frame = cellBackgroundImageView.frame
    cellBackgroundImageView.addSubview(cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView)

    // Initialize Profile Object
    let partyCellProfileObject = profileObject.createProfileObjectView()
    profileObject.profileObjectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileObjectClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    partyCellProfileObject.frame.origin.x = 10
    partyCellProfileObject.frame.origin.y = 10

    // Initialize Party Cell Title Label
    cellTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 52, y: 10, width: timelineCellView.frame.width - 62 , height: 32)
    cellTitle.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cellTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)
    cellTitle.text = "  My 16th Birthday"
    cellTitle.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cellTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Initialize Party Cell Date Label
    cellDateLabel.frame = CGRect(x: timelineCellView.frame.width / 2, y: 10, width: timelineCellView.frame.width / 2 - 15, height: 32)
    cellDateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Thin", size: 12)
    cellDateLabel.text =  "6hr ago"
    cellDateLabel.textAlignment = .right

    // Cell Description Background
    cellDescriptionBackground.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 52, width: timelineCellView.frame.width - 20, height: cellBackgroundImageView.frame.height - 62)
    cellDescriptionBackground.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cellDescriptionBackground.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cellDescriptionBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Cell Description
    cellDescription.frame = CGRect(x:  15, y: 52, width: timelineCellView.frame.width - 130, height: cellDescriptionBackground.frame.height)
    cellDescription.isScrollEnabled = false
    cellDescription.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at maximus nulla, a sollicitudin nunc. Vestibulum a tempus tortor. Phasellus dictum bibendum urna ac hendrerit. Nullam aliquet turpis et tellus iaculis, id volutpat metus sagittis. Vivamus ultrices libero quis risus blandit, eget convallis mi aliquam. Sed sed mi sit amet tellus posuere mattis vitae ac eros. Ut in placerat turpis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed condimentum at purus et rhoncus. Phasellus feugiat hendrerit hendrerit. Etiam in eleifend nisi, sit amet rhoncus sem. Sed convallis quis est id sagittis. Maecenas sodales justo nec purus rutrum, vel scelerisque odio sagittis. Nullam feugiat ac risus sit amet iaculis. Proin et libero eleifend, cursus orci ac, accumsan quam. Maecenas eget diam velit. Curabitur vehicula ornare felis a commodo. Cras enim est, feugiat id posuere eget, tempor a nisi. In lobortis et dui ultricies laoreet. Ut nibh magna, interdum vitae pellentesque tempor, ornare et sapien. Duis nec libero nec ante hendrerit dapibus. Aenean pulvinar tincidunt leo a maximus. Proin fringilla nibh posuere commodo feugiat."
    cellDescription.isEditable = false
    cellDescription.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 13)

    // Cell Image
    cellImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Placeholder 1.jpeg")
    cellImageView.frame = CGRect(x: cellDescriptionBackground.frame.width - 100, y: 62, width: 100, height: cellDescriptionBackground.frame.height - 20)
    cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cellImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Add Party Cell Subviews
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellBackgroundImageView)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellTitle)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellDateLabel)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellDescriptionBackground)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellDescription)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellImageView)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(partyCellProfileObject)
    return postCell
}

// CREATE POST CELL
func createPostCell(cellToUse postCell: TimelineCell) -> TimelineCell {

    // Initialize Post Cell View
    timelineCellView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    timelineCellView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Initialize Post Cell Background Image
    cellBackgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: timelineCellView.frame.width, height: 175)
    cellBackgroundImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Placeholder 1.jpeg")
    cellBackgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    // Bottom Blurr Effect
    cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 125, width: timelineCellView.frame.width, height: 50)
    cellBackgroundImageView.addSubview(cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView)

    // Initialize Profile Object
    let postCellProfileObject = profileObject.createProfileObjectView()
    postCellProfileObject.frame.origin.x = 10
    postCellProfileObject.frame.origin.y = 134

    // Initialize Party Cell Title Label
    cellTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 52, y: 125, width: 200, height: 40)
    cellTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)
    cellTitle.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9999960065, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    cellTitle.text = "Just Some Picks"

    // Name Label
    cellNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 52, y: 150, width: 200, height: 20)
    cellNameLabel.text = "Zachary Gameiro"
    cellNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Thin", size: 10)
    cellNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
    cellNameLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9999960065, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)

    // Initialize Post Cell Date Label
    cellDateLabel.frame = CGRect(x: timelineCellView.frame.width / 2, y: 125, width: timelineCellView.frame.width / 2 - 15, height: 50)
    cellDateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Thin", size: 12)
    cellDateLabel.text =  "5hr ago"
    cellDateLabel.textAlignment = .right


    // Add Post Cell Subviews
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellBackgroundImageView)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellTitle)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellDateLabel)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellNameLabel)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(postCellProfileObject)
    return postCell
}

 // CREATE FRIEND REQUEST CELL
func createFriendRequestCell(cellToUse friendRequestCell: TimelineCell) -> TimelineCell {

    // Initialize Friend Request Cell View
    timelineCellView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    timelineCellView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Initialize Friend Request Cell Background
    cellBackgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: timelineCellView.frame.width, height: 100)
    cellBackgroundImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Placeholder 1.jpeg")
    cellBackgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView.frame = cellBackgroundImageView.frame
    cellBackgroundImageView.addSubview(cellBackgroundImageBlurEffectView)

    // Initialize Profile Object
    let friendRequestCellProfileObject = profileObject.createProfileObjectView()
    friendRequestCellProfileObject.frame.origin.x = 10
    friendRequestCellProfileObject.frame.origin.y = 10

    // Initialize Friend Request Cell Title Label
    cellTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 52, y: 10, width: timelineCellView.frame.width - 62 , height: 32)
    cellTitle.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cellTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)
    cellTitle.text = "  Friend Request"
    cellTitle.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cellTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Initialize Friend Request Cell Description
    cellNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 52, width: timelineCellView.frame.width - 20 , height: 38)
    cellNameLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cellNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Thin", size: 15)
    cellNameLabel.text = "David Has Requested To Be Friends"
    cellNameLabel.textAlignment = .center
    cellNameLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cellNameLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Add Friend Request Cell Subviews
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellBackgroundImageView)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellTitle)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(friendRequestCellProfileObject)
    timelineCellView.addSubview(cellNameLabel)
    return friendRequestCell
}

}
```

Comment: your question isn't really clear but the general approach would be to link the button to an action in the table view cell prototype.  Now, when your table view is rendering cells with cellForRowAt, cast the cell to your custom tableViewCell class and then add the numeric index to the button using the .tag property.  Then, inside the action, cast the sender to a button and access the tag to see which row is clicked on. Im sure this question is answered elsewhere.

Comment: What if I told you all the buttons and everything inside each cell is programmatically added

Comment: as long as it's a UIButton it will still have the .tag property. This will let you find out which button in which row was clicked, then you can act appropriately.  Since it's all programattic you might have to use a TapGestureRecognizer instead of an IBAction on each button, but either way you should access to the sender.

Comment: I have it setup right now so that in my table view cell class I add a target to the button and whenever that button is clicked it calls a function inside that table cell class but I just don’t know how to perform the accruals segue. I always get errors

Comment: Again, its tough to tell what you want from the question. so inside wherever the button action is handled you will want to have a 'perform segue' function.  then you pass in the identifier of the of the segue and handle any kind of data progression with prepareForSegue. If you have many viewControllers you might be better off adding a convience init and then pushing the view onto the navigation stack programmatically.  If you are trying to switch out the actual viewcontrollers inside the tabBar you need a different approach, maybe switching out the view and not the whole controller

Comment: ultimately you should clarfiy the question

Comment: @BrooksDuBois alright I have added in my code